# Can an object literal have a component in its properties to be rendered by ngComponentOutlet?

Tags: angular, typescript, object-literal

I want to render each component using ngComponentOutlet in a certain column layout which I will style afterwards, but I'm getting null in the `component` property in this widgetsByCol, but I only have null in the html, because when doing the console.log() i see the component there. ( upon solving this problem, i want to render them dynamically, without defining the `widgets` the way I did )

This is the ts code:

```
export class WidgetListComponent implements OnInit {
  widgets: WidgetInterface[] = [
    { component: Test1Component, layoutCol: 1 },
    { component: Test2Component, layoutCol: 2 },
    { component: Test3Component, layoutCol: 3 },
    { component: Test3Component, layoutCol: 2 }
  ];

  widgetsByCol = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    for (const widget of this.widgets) {
      const { layoutCol, component } = widget;
      if (!this.widgetsByCol[layoutCol]) {
        this.widgetsByCol[layoutCol] = [];
      }
      this.widgetsByCol[layoutCol].push(component);
    }

    console.log('this.widgetsByCol', this.widgetsByCol);
  }
}
```

The html code:

```
{{widgetsByCol | json}}
<div *ngFor="let col of widgetsByCol | keyvalue">
  <div *ngFor="let widget of col.value">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="widget.component"> </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

This `{{widgetsByCol | json}}` outputs: { "1": [ null ], "2": [ null, null ], "3": [ null ] }
However the console.log outputs:

```
{
  1: [Test1Component],
  2: [Teste2Component, Teste3Component],
  3: [Test3Component]
}
```

So what's happening here ? Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close to working. You have an error in the template where you refer to `widget.component` instead of simply `widget`.

```html
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="widget"></ng-container>
```

The reason you see a difference between the console output and the `json` pipe output is because the `json` pipe stringifies your object.  You will see the same result if you called called JSON.stringify() yourself:

```js
console.log('this.widgetsByCol (stringified)', JSON.stringify(this.widgetsByCol));
// {"1":[null],"2":[null,null],"3":[null]}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-78129600?file=src%2Fmain.ts)